# Why the lock in this code is not working ?

Tags: c#

I wrote simple code ( attached ) and i don't understand why the lock on some block is not locking the scope.

The code :

```
    object locker = new object();
    private void foo(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine( string.Format( "i is {0}", i ) );
        lock( locker )
        {
            while( true )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( string.Format( "i in while loop is {0}", i ) ) ;
                foo( ++i );
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect that the calling for the foo method in the while loop will be waiting until the locker will be release ( locker scope ) - but all the calls of the foo with arg of ++i can enter to the locker block.

Comment: I think its the same thread so shouldn't lock itself (maybe someone knows it in more detail)

Comment: i definately learned something new on this one, +1

Comment: If you're already in the bathroom, and the door is already locked, and you put a *second* lock on the door, *you are still in the bathroom already.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The lock used here is reentrant. It will prevent another thread from entering the monitor, but the thread holding the lock will not be blocked.

Comment: i had no idea that's how it worked - you're 100% on this right?

Comment: @Gabriel This is exactly right; the `lock` statement in C# is re-entrant. You can't lock "yourself" out.

Comment: that's not what happens in C/C++, unless my memory is shot (and maybe it is) - just surprising that I never realized such a difference

Comment: @Gabriel: C doesn't have a `lock` statement, though.

Comment: i suppose I'm recalling mutexes and critical sections... this is C# of course so this is just noise, my bad

Comment: @Gabriel: Maybe you used the native mutexes? In Windows, mutexes are recursive. The opposite is true for POSIX systems. For a while this was true in Boost as well (versions prior to 1.35) - boost::mutex was recursive in Windows and non-recursive in POSIX.

Comment: I'm thinking back to my university days which was C/C++ on Solaris, P.S. thanks for giving me a term to think of this by - "recursive vs. non recursive mutexes" - i'll remember that now

Answer (score 10):

The lock keyword is just syntactic sugar around the `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` methods. As seen in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx) for `Monitor`:

> It is legal for the same thread to invoke Enter more than once without it blocking;

Calling `lock(object)` from the same thread more than once has no effect other than to increase the lock count.

Comment: is there another type of lock that behaves the way the poster expected Monitor/lock to behave?

Comment: @Gabriel, you could use `AutoResetEvent` for that.

Comment: @Gabriel `SpinLock` is not re-entrant, IOW, `SpinLonk.Enter` will fail if called on the same thread that already holds the lock; the two aren't exactly the same but would have worked as the OP seemed to expect.

Comment: @svick `AutoResetEvent` isn't a lock.

Comment: i guess maybe the question is: what scenario would require the same thread to lock itself out of a critical section of code?  I can't think of one off the top of my head...

Answer (score 1):

Lock doesn't apply if you are on the same thread. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When you make a recursive call here on thread say t1, it is not spinning off a separate thread. The recursive call is being made on the same thread t1.

As t1 is already holding the lock, it does not have to wait for the lock.